# How can I prevent non-math overflowing into margin when using textsubscript?

Tags: line-breaking

I am using `\textsubscript` for subscripting a non-math data . but it is long enough to cause overflow into the margin. What are the possible solutions?(may be like writing subscript in 2 lines)

Comment: `\sloppy` before the paragraph?

Comment: It didn't work .Just to be clear do you mean \sloppy before the starting of subscript?

Comment: Long ˢᵘᵖᵉʳ/ˢᵘᵇˢᶜʳᶦᵖᵗˢ ᵃʳᵉ ᵖʳᵉᵗᵗʸ ᵇᵃᵈ

Comment: @Curious no I meant what I said, `\sloppy` before the paragraph

Comment: @David Carlisle : yeah I tried that too .. it didn;t work either

Comment: @percusse : I know that .. but my assignment demands .. actually I am writing Relational Algebra queries in Latex , so subscripts are exceptionally big.

Comment: It seems that you have only two option: (i) rephrase text that your math expression will move in center of text line. or (ii) write it as displayed equation.

Comment: @Curious "it didn't work" is not a useful description:-) what did you do, and what happened?  (see my answer which provides a reproducible test document)

Comment: updated example with line breakable subscript.....

Comment: I am sorry for the bad  description . Thanks for your patient answer. I found it useful . Just to mention , I thought of a small hack of splitting a single subscript into 2 adjacent subscripts with a \newline between them and it worked . But I know this aint an efiicient solution as it just fits my case of having just one long subscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please always provide an example document,

here are two possibilities

first showing a breakable subscript that wraps at word spaces

second showing a paragraph with overfull lines in the margin, with `\sloppy` and with `\raggedright`

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\xsubscript#1{{\scriptsize \xxsubscript#1 ^ }}
\def\xxsubscript#1 {%
\ifx^#1\else
{\normalsize\textsubscript{#1}} %space needed
\expandafter\xxsubscript
\fi
}
\begin{document}


\hrule

\bigskip

a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}!


\hrule

\bigskip

a paragraph\xsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\xsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\xsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\xsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\xsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\xsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\xsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\xsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\xsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}
a paragraph\xsubscript{with a long subscript that
could go on for more than a line, it is really really really really really really long}!


\bigskip

\hrule
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\hrule

\bigskip

a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}!


\bigskip

\hrule

\bigskip

{\sloppy
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}!

}
\bigskip

\hrule

{\raggedright
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}
a paragraph\textsubscript{with a long subscript}!

}
\bigskip

\hrule
\end{document}
```